# Search for comma values inside query?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, full-text-search

How can I search for a value say

> 23,000

on a VARBINARY(MAX) filestream column in SQL Server 2008 R2 ? This won't work

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_Files WHERE CONTAINS(SystemFile, '%[23,000]%');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its just you have `%` and full text search uses *

```
select
*
from tbl_Files
Where contains(SystemFile, '"*23,000*"')
```

I have a full text index with phone numbers in it and this works too

```
select
*
from tbl_Files
Where contains(SystemFile, '0116')
```

Comment: Figured it out, using '"1,102,942,489'" instead of wildcard '*' solved the problem. Any reason you used "'*'" ?

Comment: " is the text delimiter in FTS

Comment: I got that working without using asterik *. Why did you used asterik ? Is it a wildcard operator for FTS?

Comment: Asterisk is the wildcard operator - http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlforum/archive/2011/02/28/forum-faq-how-can-i-perform-wildcard-searches-in-full-text-search.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_Files WHERE CAST(SystemFile AS NVARCHAR) LIKE '%23,000%'
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this one :

```
select * from  dbo.tbl_Files where   CAST(SystemFile as int)  like '%23000%'
```

If you have a `VARBINARY` datatype for a column then you should have to `CAST` that value , because it is stored as bianry value in table.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The query is returning null however the search string exists.

Comment: Hi Damien,you are looking for that particular value in that field VARBINARY(MAX) that stored binary data.. or you need original value as '23000'. and stored as binary in table as '0x000059D8'

Comment: I am looking for the matching value in the file for e.g 23,000 together with the comma separators.

Comment: try this one : SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_Files WHERE cast(SystemFile as varchar) like '%23,000%'

Answer (score 0):

try this one :
SELECT * FROM dbo.tbl_Files WHERE cast(SystemFile as varchar) like '%23,000%'